# Why is David obsessed with "Lawrence of Arabia"?

Tags: alien-franchise, character-motivation, prometheus

In *Prometheus*, while the other members of the crew are in hibernation, David busies himself watching *Lawrence of Arabia*. He seems so obsessed by the film and the eponymous character that he imitates Lawrence's lines and even copies his hairstyle.

What is the director trying to tell us here?

Comment: Because it's a bad a** film that's why!!!111  Seriously though, it's one of the greatest film works of all time, as well as being semi-biographical.  Some claim that almost every scene in Lawrence of Arabia is drawn from a real life event.

Comment: I don't know, but now I feel I have to watch *Lawrence of Arabia* again to find out.  I didn't like it the first time around.  Ugh.

Comment: here is the secret to enjoying Lawrence of Arabia : when you get to all the parts where they are riding through the desert for like 10 minute stretches, just skip through those parts.  It turns a 3+ hour movie into a <2 hour movie, and makes it far more enjoyable!!

Comment: @zipquincy: Blasphemy! The scenic shots are the best parts of the movie IMHO. Really spectacular.

Comment: Until recently, I had avoided _Lawrence_ because of all the jokey references to its length and tedium. _Prometheus_, and the discussion about David's obsession with the film, changed my mind. If you haven't seen _Lawrence of Arabia_, please give it a try. It helps to break it down into roughly one hour segments. The film is rich in texture and detail.

Comment: @ObscureRobot: “It helps to break it down into roughly one hour segments.” Dearie me, you kids and your internet-ravaged attention spa- hey look, this site has a newsletter! *Lawrence* was originally shown with an interval at the halfway point, which I think is maintained in DVD releases. I needed a bit of a rest at that point.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite omg. That's hilarious!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I saw it as David identifying with T.E. Lawrence who, in the film at least, was shown as being conflicted in his identity - and perhaps his loyalty - between the British and Arabian cultures. I imagine David felt betwixt and between, being both humanlike but not actually human. I briefly considered the masochist subtext to Lawrence's character, but...no.

Edit - Found this:

> David has been watching Lawrence of Arabia while the crew of
>   Prometheus was in stasis for two years, why that movie?
>
> Lindelof: Ridley and I started talking about Lawrence of Arabia, for
>   some reason, very early on in our process. I'm a huge David Lean fan —
>   we were talking about The Bridge on the River Kwai and then Peter
>   O'Toole etc. etc. we just started saying oh what if David was just
>   obsessed with Lawrence of Arabia? Why would he be obsessed with
>   Lawrence of Arabia, and i think the short answer was: Lawrence is a
>   stranger in a strange land. A white man who is entirely different,
>   ultimately becomes the most pivotal figure in that movie, independent
>   of his differences. That felt slightly analogical to what we wanted to
>   do with David.

[Source (io9.com)](http://io9.com/5917448/all-of-your-lingering-prometheus-questions-answered?utm_campaign=socialflow_io9_facebook&utm_source=io9_facebook&utm_medium=socialflow) - thanks to Thaddeus for posting the link in [this thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18078/what-did-david-say-to-the-engineer)

Answer (score 3):

It's a personal tribute of Ridley Scott to one of his favorite films

Comment: You are no doubt correct .... but do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Peter Weyland also mentions T.E. Lawrence in his 2023 TED speech.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté *Exactly.* David is obsessed with Lawrence of Arabia because Weyland is obsessed with Lawrence of Arabia. Father programmed son. So the real question is: why is Weyland obsessed with  Lawrence of Arabia? And the TED talk hints at an answer I think.